# Quiver algebra as a wreath product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, quiver, wreath-product

I'm having trouble understanding a definition of a quiver Hecke algebra.

Suppose $k$ is a commutative ring, and $\Omega$ a finite set. We build a quiver $Q_{\Omega,n}$ with vertex set $\Omega^n$. Then $S_n$ acts on $\Omega^n$, so define the arrow set to be 
$$
s_i=s_{i,v}\colon v\to s_i(v)
$$
for $1\leq i\leq n-1$, $v\in\Omega^n$
and
$$
x_i=x_{i,v}\colon v\to v
$$
for $1\leq i\leq n$ and $v\in \Omega^n$.

The define the quiver algebra $A$ with the quiver above and relations
$$
s_i^2=1, s_is_j=s_js_i,\ |i-j|>1,\ s_is_{i+1}s_i=s_{i+1}s_is_{i+1}
$$
$$
x_ix_j=x_jx_i,\ s_ix_j=x_js_i,\ j\neq i,i+1,\ s_ix_i=x_{i+1}s_i.
$$

Supposedly this implies $A=k[x]^\Omega\wr S_n$, the wreath product. I don't understand what it means that the quiver algebra is a wreath product. I only know how to make sense of a wreath product of groups, so even viewing $k[x]$ (I assume this is shorthand for $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$) as a group, it seems like $k[x]^\Omega\wr S_n$ only carries a group structure, so how can it be the quiver algebra? (Also, I suspect should $k[x]$ be indexed by $\Omega^n$, not $\Omega$? I can't think of a sensible way $S_n$ would act on $\Omega$.)

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your terminologies and notation (as well as the question).  First, it seems to me you are asking about quiver Hecke algebras, not quiver algebra; they are two completely different thing.  A quiver algebra is the algebra with basis given by compositions of arrows in a quiver.  On the other hand, a quiver Hecke algebra, is an algebra defined by Hecke-like relation determined the structure of the quiver.  Second, what is $k[x]^{\Omega}$?  Third, what do you mean by $k[x]$ indexed by $\Omega^n$ or $\Omega$?

Comment: It seems to me the first important issue I can clarify for you is that the wreath product of an algebra $A$ is given as follows.  Take the $n$-fold tensor product $A^{\otimes n}$ of $A$ over the underlying field (or some nice ring), then the symmetric group of rank $n$ acts on $A^{\otimes n}$ by permuting the coordinates.  So now you can define the semi-direct product of $A^{\otimes n}$ with $k\mathfrak{S}_n$, which is what we call the wreath product $A\wr\mathfrak{S}_n$.  For more details, you can refer to J.Chuang-K.M.Tan's Reprsentations of wreath product algebras

Comment: @Aaron You're right, sorry, I mean to ask about the quiver Hecke algebra. I'm reading the paper Quiver Hecke Algebras and 2-Lie Algebras by Rouquier, and this is Section 3.2 on page 12. The notation $k[x]^\Omega$, is not defined, so I'm guessing it's tuples with coordinates in $k[x]$, indexed by elements of $\Omega$. I thought $S_n$ would act on $(p(x)_\alpha,p(x)_\beta,\dots,p(x)_\eta)\in k[x]^{\Omega^n}$ by  $S_n$ acting on the the $n$-tuples in $\Omega$ $\alpha,\beta...\in\Omega^n$ by permuting the usual indices $1,\dots,n$ there.

Comment: Anyway, I think you're second comment is what I'm after. Is the semidirect product of $A^{\otimes n}$ and $kS^n$ the set $A^{\otimes n}\otimes kS_n$ with usual addition but multiplication on $A\wr S_n$ given by $(a_1\otimes\cdots\otimes a_n\otimes \sigma)(b_1\otimes\cdots\otimes b_n\otimes\tau)=(a_1b_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes a_nb_{\sigma(n)}\otimes \sigma\tau)$?